# Left and Right aligning of a list on the same line in sequence

Tags: html, list, inline, alignment

Trying to use a list with 5 (or more items) gotten the code to work but trying to get it to work as the desired image shows.

I'm very new at css so please bear with me.  thanks

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Desired:

    Item 1                                     Item 2  Item 3  Item 4  Item 5

Currently: 

    Item 1                                     Item 5  Item 4  Item 3  Item 2
```

CSS

```
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
}

#navlist #right
{
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}

#navlist li a
{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li id="right">Item 2</li>
    <li id="right">Item 3</li>
    <li id="right">Item 4</li>
    <li id="right">Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `float:left;` on all of the `li`s?

Comment: Lacer: Use CSS class names for duplacates, not IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work jsfiddle.net/Z3a6Z/23. thanks everyone for the direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `display: table` in your CSS:

```
#navlist
{
    display: table;
}

#navlist li
{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#navlist li:last-child
{
    padding-right: 0;
}

#navlist li.span-full
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

And your markup now looks like this:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li class="span-full">Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QfD6J/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QfD6J/)**

Using this CSS

```
#navlist li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none
}
#navlist li:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-right:60px;
}
```

You can also use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

Comment: thanks alot for the direction.  Is there a way to make it more dynamic?  instead of specifying the margin?  so as you add items it automatically fills the space from the right?

Comment: yes.  I kinda got it working like using this http://jsfiddle.net/Z3a6Z/23/  would this work? any issues in using this?

Comment: Ok it doesn't seem to line up in IE 7.  Any way to fix that? i have the code here. jsfiddle.net/Z3a6Z/23

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
float: left;
```

inside `#navlist li` and `#navlist #right`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using 2 lists with one floating on the right? http://jsfiddle.net/rEc3V/

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>Item 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```